# Reset function in JS keeps reloading page

Tags: javascript, reset

I have a reset function in my codes that is keeping my form on a reloading loop.

When I click on my Calculate Button, the divtext that I am trying to display just "Blink" and it will go off.

I only want it to reset when reset button is clicked though. Don't know where it went wrong. Here are my codes.

```js
function calculateDate() {
  var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
  var endDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
  var dvtextless60 = document.getElementById("dvtextless60");
  var dvtext61182 = document.getElementById("dvtext61182");
  var dvtextmore183 = document.getElementById("dvtextmore183");
  var Difference_In_Time = new Date(endDate).getTime() - new Date(startDate).getTime();
  var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);

  if (Difference_In_Days < 60){
    document.getElementById("dvtextless60").style.display = "block";
  } else if (Difference_In_Days > 60 && Difference_In_Days <= 182){
    document.getElementById("dvtext61182").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dvtextmore183").style.display = "block";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("daysCalculator").innerHTML = greeting;
}

function resetForm(){
  document.getElementById('rCalculator').reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="rCalculator">
<pre>
Enter Start Date: <input type="date" name="startDate" id="startDate"/><br>

Enter End Date: <input type="date" name="endDate" id="endDate"/><br>

Total Days : <span id="daysCalculator"></span>

<div id="dvtextless60" style="display:none"> 
<span style="font-size:18px"><b>Too Short</b></span>
<br>

</div>

<div id="dvtext61182" style="display:none"> 
<span style="font-size:18px"><b>Almost There</b></span>

</div>

<div id="dvtextmore183" style="display:none"> 
<span style="font-size:18px"><b>Too Long</b></span>

</div>


<button id="calculate" onclick="calculateDate();">Calculate</button>   <button id="reset" onclick="resetForm();">Reset</button> 

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this adding a `type="button"` to your reset button.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for suggesting and it does stop the looping but now it doesn't reset at all. Any idea why?

Comment: Also change the ID of your reset button, if you use "reset" as  name/id it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that you are using html form

I suggest you to edit your button with <type="submit"> and <type="reset">
and you can remove the button onClick and use form onsubmit={}

```
<form id="rCalculator" onsubmit="calculateDate()">

Enter Start Date: <input type="date" name="startDate" id="startDate"/><br>

Enter End Date: <input type="date" name="endDate" id="endDate"/><br>

<button id="calculate" type="submit">Calculate</button>
<button id="reset" type="reset">Reset</button>

</form>
```

Have an event.preventDefault() method in your calculate function. This way you can eliminate resetForm() function.